# Unable to build quazip. moc compiler dooesn't run. Command line finds no relevant classes

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, quazip

I just downloaded the latest version of `quazip`. I'm using visual studio 2012 and QT 5.1.

There are three moc files required. The visual studio project doesn't seem to create them. I don't see the moc compiler even trying. I tried to build them from the command line, but I ended up with empty files. The linker then generates a lot of these errors

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct
>   QMetaObject const QuaZipFile::staticMetaObject"
>   (?staticMetaObject@QuaZipFile@@2UQMetaObject@@B)

This is the command that I used to run the moc compiler (and similar command for the other two files):

```
C:\Tools64\v2.0.6\Qt-5.1.0\bin\moc -o moc_quazipfile.cpp quazipfile.cpp
```

that command generates the following error:

> quazipfile.cpp(0): Note: No relevant classes found. No output
>   generated.

I do see the `Q_OBJECT` definition in `QuaZipFile`, so it should have found something.

Comment: The macros are likely in the header files, not .cpp files.

Comment: Are you saying I should be doing "C:\Tools64\v2.0.6\Qt-5.1.0\bin\moc -o moc_quazipfile.cpp quazipfile.h" ?

Comment: Yes, of course! Just grep/file search those macros - you'll see where they are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should run moc manually...

Are you sure the Qt plugin / addin for Visual Studio is up to date?

Alternatively, you can just use qmake to compile.

Run:

```
qmake quazip.pro
```

This will generate the makefiles according to your Qt SDK mkspecs. If you are using MSVC, it should generate a makefile for nmake.

Then, simply type

```
nmake -f Makefile
```

from the MSVC command line prompt (you should have several entries in your start menu, depending on the architecture you are compiling for)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the suggestion about to do "C:\Tools64\v2.0.6\Qt-5.1.0\bin\moc -o moc_quazipfile.cpp quazipfile.h" may have worked.

Evidently, the visual studio project released with the latest quazip is not functional.